# Do I have to use multiple "that"s for the multiple clauses?

Tags: clauses, optional-that

Which is correct between the followings?

> We assume that (clause), and that (clause).
>
> We assume that (clause), and (clause).

---

My sentence is as follows:

> We define a function f with respect to x, which indicates performance of the computer. We assume that the function f is a quadratic form, and that the larger the function value is, the better the performance is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repeating **that** makes the structure of your sentence clearer, and clarity is a virtue.

Without **that** ...

"and the larger the function value is, the better the performance is"

could be taken as an appended *fact*, not as a second assumption.